# How to render the data from two API calls in one component?

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch

I'm wondering how you can have two API calls, and render the data from both in one component?

My problem is this: I'm fetching dog images from an external API, and dog names from an internal API, and I want them to display together in the browser as part of the same component - but they can't. I can get either the pictures rendering, or the dog names rendering, but not both together. I think it's because of how I've structured my project, which is as follows:

App.js (parent component)

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css'
import DogList from './DogList'
import Dogue from './Dogue'
import axios from 'axios'
import DogNameList from './DogNameList'

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
    loading: false,
    dog: [],
    dogName: []
  }
}


setData = async () => {
  const x = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breed/hound/images");
  const y = await x.json();
  const z = await y.message;
  
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    if (i <= 9) {
      newArr.push(z[i]);
    }
   }
  return newArr;
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true,
    });
  
    const dogPromise = this.setData();
    const dogNamePromise = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/dogs');
  
    Promise.all([
        dogPromise,
        dogNamePromise
    ])
      .then(([dogResponse, dogNameResponse]) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          dog: dogResponse,
          dogName: dogNameResponse.data,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }


render() {
  return (
    
     this.state.loading ? <h1> Dogues Loading.....</h1>
    :
    <div>
      <h1>Rate My Dogue</h1>
      <DogList dogs = {this.state.dog} id = {this.state.id}/>
      <DogNameList name ={this.state.dogName} />
    </div>
    
  );
}

}
export default App;
```

Props are passed to two other components, DogList and DogNameList:

DogNameList.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Dogue from './Dogue'

const DogNameList = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            {
            props.name.map(name => {
                return <Dogue name = {name} key={name.id}/>
            })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default DogNameList
```

DogList.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Dogue from './Dogue'


const DogList = (props) => {
    return (

        <div className = 'img-container'>
        {
            props.dogs.map((doggie, index) => {
            return <Dogue key = {index} dogList = {doggie}/>
            })
        }
        </div>

    )
}

export default DogList
```

Dogue.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class Dogue extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {

        }
    }

    render(){

    return (
        <div>
            <img className = 'img' src = {this.props.dogList}/>
            <br/>
            <form className = 'form'>
                <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Enter dog name'/>
                <br/>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
    <h2>dog name:{this.props.name.dogName} </h2>
        </div>
    )
    }
}


export default Dogue
```

So- I think the problem is this: I'm feeding the results of two different maps (from two different components, DogList and DogNameList) to Dogue.jsx via props - and in doing so, I'm possibly creating two instances of Dogue? Anyway, something wierd is happening, and I attribute it to having these DogList and DogNameList **both** feeding props into Dogue. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the below-mentioned approach. Instead of using `Promise.all` you can use async/await to fetch the data as shown below. For that make your `ComponentDidMount()` async and use `await` for both `dogPromise` and `dogNamePromise`

Also, in your render method, remove your call for `DogNameList` and pass a prop `name` to your `DogList` component

```
.....................
.....................

async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true,
    });
  
    let dogPromise = await this.setData();
    let dogNamePromise = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/dogs'); 

    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      dog: dogResponse,
      dogName: dogNameResponse.data,
    });
  }
................
................
................
   
render() {
  return (
    
     this.state.loading ? <h1> Dogues Loading.....</h1>
    :
    <div>
      <h1>Rate My Dogue</h1>
      <DogList dogs = {this.state.dog} id = {this.state.id} name={this.state.dogName} />
      //<DogNameList name ={this.state.dogName} />
    </div>
    
  );
}

..............
..............
```

Also modify your `Dogue.jsx` and `DogList.jsx` accordingly

```
const DogList = props => {
  return (
    <div className="img-container">
      {props.dogs.map((doggie, index) => {
        return (
          <Dogue
            key={index}
            dogList={doggie}
            name={props.name && props.name[index] && props.name[index].dogName}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Giving a reference to the codesandbox I tried https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-rsx0h?file=/index.js

As I don't have the dog names API I used the dog images API twice to replicate the issue. Also, do check out the `console` logs

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your help. I integrated your code and it worked, but I had problems when I replaced the external API call with the internal call (from ``` let dogNamePromise = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breed/hound/images"); ```  to  ```  let dogNamePromise = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/dogs');  ```. I'm getting the error 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined', so I think the error is to do with the form the data is coming back as, which is as follows: ``` [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "dogName": "bruce"
    },
]```

Comment: ok can we discuss in the chat room. I can explain in more detail

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218006/discussion-on-api-error please join this room